# Why my USB disk is not showing up?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

My USB disk can be detected and mounted  on my home Windows 10 computer. When I  connect to my office Windows10 PC, it is not detected. My friend's USB disk can be shown.

Suggestions

Comment: Is your USB drive not showing up in Windows File Explorer but can be seen in Disk Management? Or Is it missing from both Windows File Explorer and Disk Management? To make it clear, go to "This PC" > "Manage" > "Disk Management" and check whether your USB drive shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the USB drive is actually enabled in device manager. Right click on the Windows start menu, and select device manager. Go to Disk Drives and find the USB. click on it and select properties. Make sure that it is not turned off. Go to the drivers tab, and if the drive is not enabled, do so.

It is also possible it just does not have a drive letter, which Windows requires to be able to recognize a drive in File Explorer. To check, right click on the Windows logo in the bottom right, and then select disk management. If you are not an admin, then you may not be able to access this menu. Look for your flash drive in the menu. If it is there, make sure to give it a drive letter. This is done by right clicking on the partition.

If it is not recognized by disk management, you need to use diskpart. To run this, open a command prompt as an administrator and type `diskpart` and hit enter. When the new diskpart windows pops up, run the command `list disk`. Find the USB drive. If it appears, then it is recognized by the PC, just not in a readable format. This can happen with some types of file systems.